# 'Raphael' is undefined in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser, raphael

I am trying to get some mouse event management to work in IE using Raphael.

But I am getting an error 'Raphael' is undefined in Internet Explorer 9 even though it works well in other browsers, like Chrome.

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agarcian/q8Evm/1/) and the code:

```
<div id="sample"></div>
<div id="status"></div>



var width = 400;
var height = 200;
var paper = Raphael(document.getElementById('sample'), 0, 0, width, height);

var rect = paper.rect(0, 0, width, height);
rect.attr({
    stroke: "#888",
    fill: "#eaeaea"
});



var circle = paper.circle(50, 60, 20);
    circle.attr({
        fill: "#f90"
    });

$(circle.node).mouseenter(function(e){
        $('#status').html('Entered circle');
    });
$(circle.node).mouseleave(function(e){
        $('#status').html('left circle');
    });
```

It is using this version of the library:  https://raw.github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/master/raphael-min.js​

Can you assist in identifying why is not working in IE?

Thanksk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the default hosting on github, see [Issue 173](https://github.com/jsfiddle/jsfiddle-docs-alpha/issues/173)

The fix is to change your Manage Resource link from the one linked to on raphaeljs.com that points to http://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/raw/master/raphael.js to the one hosted on cdnjs.com - http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js.